# Xcode not showing run devices

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a quick question regarding XCode that I have been trying to solve for the last week.  If you look at the screenshot my IOS devices are not being displayed in the toolbar by the run button.  Could somebody show me how to display this?  I'm trying to test on different devices and also trying to compile my source code (i know how to compile).  Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: if your xcode version is 7.0 then restart it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this happen because of layout issues where `xcode` would hide the bar with the devices if the screen is too narrow rather than displaying it beneath for example.

If playing with the `size/resolution/layout` doesn't help, you can go to `Product > Destination > List` of devices available